# Customize search filter in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have implemented a search filter using jquery when the user types in. I want the header and the child elements to be filtered when the user types in. The issue is when i search the child element ie. 333 (example shown in the fiddler), 222 also appears which should not happen; only 333 should get filtered.

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var SEARCHWORD = this.value;

    $("#list li").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();

        $('h3:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('li').show();
        $('table:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('li').show();
        $('table:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').show().siblings('table').hide();

        if (SEARCHWORD == "") {
            $('#list').find('table:hidden').show();
        }
    });
});
```

I have attached the jsfiddle link "[My Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3LFL/)"

Comment: When you search for '333', you show the nearest `li`, which also contains '222'. So you need to change your logic or your HTML.

Comment: Click on "run" in the fiddle, it gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to add table before every table row (tr), rather than putting 2 tr's in 1 table.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='a1'>
         <h3>Header1</h3> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>aaa</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>xxx</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>def</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li id='a2'>
         <h3>Header2</h3> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>333</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>222</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>111</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery (not changed)**

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var SEARCHWORD = this.value;
     $("#list li").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('h3:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('li').show()
        $('table:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').closest('li').show();
        $('table:contains(' + SEARCHWORD + ')').show().siblings('table').hide();
        if (SEARCHWORD == "") {
            $('#list').find('table:hidden').show();
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3LFL/1/)

Comment: That's correct; but when i tried to put values like 402711, 402722 in the same header and then start typing in just "4027", both the values needs to show up which is not happening. Please have a look in the fiddle [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/z3LFL/3/)

Comment: That's right, that is because you have an .each, first it shows one, then it hides it again in the next loop. Let me try to fix it for you.

Comment: Any updates. i think that could be the reason, if you have fixed it, let me know. Thanks

Comment: I tried fixing it for 15 minutes or so, but ended up having spaghetti code... I almost fixed it but it didn't work perfectly so I removed it...

Comment: Ok, am also trying it but couldn't make it still.

Comment: I got a solution, but the performance is slow. I mean the search is too slow.